# Knapsack for table

Tags: c#, knapsack-problem

I have a problem that I can't solve. There is this table:

[image: table]

I have to optimally allocate 1 million dollars among the five products. I think it looks like knapsack problem but I am not sure. If I want to solve this for what should I look? If it is knapsack how should I change an original knapsack solution to fit mine problem?

Comment: You might want to go to http://math.stackexchange.com with that question

Comment: Sounds like [linear optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) to me, rather than a knapsack problem.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the problem described can be solved via dynamic programming in a way very similar to the [0/1 Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). However, the recurrence relation has to be adapted. Instead of considering 2 cases at each stage (namely discarding or taking the respective item), 6 cases have to be considered, which correspond to discarding the item (not investing in the product), taking choice 1 (using investment 1) to taking choice 10 (using investment 10). Although each item will have 11 profit values (for each of the choices), the state space remains two-dimensional (one axis for the minimum weight, i.e. the invested amount, and one axis for the enumeration of items). In more detail, a formulation in pseudocode could be as follows. For ease of presentaion, access outside of the state space is supposed to yield a value of positive infinity.

```
// Input:
// Values (stored in array v_1,...,v_10)
// Weights (stored in arrays w_1,...w_10)
// Number of distinct items (n)
// Knapsack capacity (W)

for j from 0 to W do:
    m[0, j] := 0

for i from 1 to n do:
    for j from 0 to W do:
        m[i, j] := max(m[i-1, j],
                       m[i-1, j-w_1[i-1]] + v_1[i-1],
                       ...,
                       m[i-1, j-w_10[i-1]] + v_10[i-1])
```